# Where should I store csv files created by cron in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am running a daily cron that runs through the Cakephp Console shell and produces a CSV file that will eventually be parsed.

What I want to do is store each day's CSV file in a folder somewhere that's not accessible to the public.

Is there an ideal location for this? If I wanted it publicly accessible, I'd stick it in `webroot/files`.

Is it best for me just to create some random folder within the `app` or is there somewhere else that's already been designated for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any place designated for that already, but you're right to put it outside of webroot.

If it were me, I'd probably put it in `tmp/csvs/` or something like that.  it's already a writable directory, and it sounds like you don't really need it to be stored for long periods of time, so putting it in a "temporary" folder seems to make sense.

Comment: Well I do believe I would like them archived rather than temporary.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `APP/webroot/files/` would only be good for files that should be publicly accessible.

If you want them "below" the surface, store them in `APP/files/`
There they will not be reachable directly and can be stored in a more permanent way.

If they will become a lot of files it makes also sense to group them by year or some other subfoldering scheme:

```
APP/files/2013/
APP/files/2014/
```

etc.
This way accessing them will be faster with a huge amount of files.